# Porting silverlight WP8 app to WP8.1 RT app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I've been porting a WP8 app to WinRT (WP8.1). What I want to do is to write all of the existing user's data to a file in WP8 and then when he migrates to WP8.1 read that file and restore all the history etc. The problem that I'm facing is that the file I save is nowhere to be found in RT. WP8 path is isostore://abc.txt while in RT path's look like ms-appdata://. Is this even possible? Are the files carried over or, deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1 RT apps, the IsolatedStorage folder is migrated to the Local folder.
So if you previously had a file in `isostore://abc.txt`, it'll be available as `ms-appdata:///local/abc.txt`.

Comment: Thanks! What about IsolatedStorageSettings?

Comment: Probably to `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings`, not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

what i think in this case, if your user have wp8 app installed and you provide an update of wp8.1 app, then your new update will totally replace the previous version and re-install the app.

So here when re-install happens, then your user's data stored in IsolatedStorage will be removed before new version gets installed.

I'm not sure about this but this is what my experience says.
Hope that helps..